# Lisp: Find the setf way of doing the equivalent of fset

Tags: lisp, elisp, setf

Find the ***setf*** way of doing the equivalent of ***fset*** in lisp.

Comment: This is not a question. What do you mean by *fset*? What is the problem? Do you have an example? What did you try? What is the expected result?

Comment: In lisp code, the _fset_ command does certain things.
We need to find a way to use _setf_ to do the same things that _fset_ can do.

Comment: what certain things? can you describe them in your own words?

Comment: This is homework, what did you try to do? Did you search on google? (e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Generalized-Variables.html)

Comment: I don't think this question is "unclear"; but it is excessively terse, and on review I must agree that it does read like a direct quote of a homework question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(symbol-function 'foo)` is a Generalized Variable in elisp, so you can use:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'forward-word) #'backward-word)
```

as an alternative to:

```
(fset 'forward-word #'backward-word)
```

(As a side-note, you can do the same thing with `cl-letf` as a replacement for the deprecated `flet` when you want to override a function using dynamic scope.)